# Как искать в Google точную фразу по JAVA файлам?

Tags: java, github, search, google-search

Нужно найти все случаи использования `(int)(short)` в файлах `.java`.

Один из таких случаев здесь: https://gist.github.com/rabestro/47002efeb9e725b98470d95c88dc6670

Как правильно искать в Google/GitHub чтобы найти все подобные случаи?